# Can a cannery license can be attached to a home kitchen?

Tags: canning

I'm wondering if a cannery license can be attached to a home kitchen. I have already searched the appropriate government websites. I'm not referring to "cottage food" regulations. I'm referring to a CDPH cannery license in California, but, I'm also interested in answers relating to cannery licenses from other states.

Comment: Can you supply your general location? Rules/policies likely vary significantly.

Comment: My understanding is that there are concerns about what they’re allowed to inspect (so they can drop by unannounced to inspect), which is more problematic with a home.  And you might have kids or other people cooking in there that don’t know the sanitation rules, etc.  And then there’s the zoning issues (is a commercial use approved for the property?), insurance (will your homeowners insurance cover it, or even allow you to keep your insurance with it attached?), etc.

Comment: The biggest barrier to this I can see is that, in order to obtain a CDPH cannery license, you need to demonstrate that your "cannery" adheres to all relevant California and federal food safety regulations, and that would be extremely difficult to pass muster with a home kitchen simply due to the lack of environment control - you can't guarantee that there won't be any risk of contamination when kids/pets are running back and forth through it all day, for instance.